# Docker Data/Named Volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am trying to wrap my mind around Docker volumes but I must have some things missing to understand it.

Let's say I have a Python app that require some initialisation depending on env variables. What I'm trying to achieve is having a *"Code only image"* from which I can start containers that would be mounted at executions. The entrypoint script of the *Main container* will then read and generate some files from/on the *Code only container*.

I tried to create an image to have a copy of the code

```
FROM ubuntu    
COPY ./app /usr/local/code/app
```

Then `docker create --name code_volume`

And with docker-compose:

```
app:  
    image: python/app
    hostname: app
    ports:
        - "2443:443"
    environment:
        - ENV=stuff
    volumes_from:
        - code_volume
```

I get an error from the app container saying it can't find a file in /usr/local/code/app/src but when I run code_volume with bash then ls into the folder, the file is sitting there...

I tried to change access rights, add /bin/true (seeing it in some examples) but I just can't get what I want to be working. I checked the `docker volume create` feature but it seems to be for storing/sharing data afterward

What am I missing ? Is the entrypoint script executed before volumes are mounted ? Is there any best practices for cases like this that don't involve mounting folders and keeping one copy for every container ? Should I be thinking my containers over again ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not declare the volume on code_volume container upon creation.

```
 docker create -v /usr/local/code/app --name code_volume
```